# In the US, can a manufacturer enforce how their products are used?

Tags: united-states

Petzl (a company manufacturing outdoors equipment) has the following [statement on their website](https://www.petzl.com/US/en/Sport/Self-belaying-is-prohibited-):

> **Self-belaying is prohibited!**
>
> We cannot ignore the fact that some people use the GRIGRI as a
>   self-belay device. Many internet sites give tips on modifying your
>   device for this use.
>
> Above all, this technique increases the risks to the climber. Firstly,
>   the climber does not hold the brake side of the rope.
>
> Additionally, in case of a fall ,the GRIGRI can be blocked against the
>   rock, the positioning system (positioning strap), or other, thus
>   negating its braking function. The climber could fall to the ground.
>   Finally, **remember that any product modification outside of Petzl
>   facilities is formally prohibited** (see Instructions for Use).
>
> **Self-belaying with the GRIGRI is prohibited.**

Are these provisions actually enforceable, in accordance to US law? If it matters, Petzl products are sold in regular stores that don't require customers to sign an explicit waiver before making a purchase.

Comment: Its probably not enforceable per se, but having that provision publicly visible and prominent would probably go a long way to a good defence if a suit was brought alleging liability in the case where the product was used in that manner and caused injury.  Adding this as a comment as its just thoughts without anything to back it up right now.

Comment: This seems to be misguided example for the question. Petzl has absolutely no interest or Intention to enforce these rules. The statement is not intended to prevent people from doing anything specific, it's designed to limit liability if things go wrong.

Comment: @Hilmar I guess they use the word "prohibited" in a different way then?

Comment: What do you mean under "enforce" and "prohibit"? If you mean a company suing you if they catch you using their product in a way not endorsed by them, then the answer will be no. If it's about you losing your warranty or the right to be compensated for damages, then yes.

Comment: @vsz I don't know what Petzl was trying to say. To me "prohibited" means I could be sued for it. To them it seems that it means "you'll lose your warranty".

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica: You are confusing "intent" and "means". The "intent" is to limit Petzl's liability and protect them in case of a law suit. The "means" to implement the protection is to create a statement that explicit prohibits the risky activity. Enforcement would be counter productive for them: it's expensive, bad PR and will annoy and detract customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

It's your device, you can do what you like with it (subject to the law - you can't hit people with it. Unless they want to be hit: whatever turns you on, turns you on).

However, if you do operate it outside their instructions then they would not be legally liable if it failed and injured you or someone else or set fire to the cat or whatever. The "prohibition" would limit their legal liability.

Answer (score 3):

This would be very unusual but if the device were rented or leased rather than sold the manufacturer could impose constraints because it remains their property.